# Loading Preferences in to a Mac Kernel Extension

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, kernel, device-driver

Greetings!

I am working on a kernel extension driver for OSX. It is a simple keyboard filter. I have preferences that are set through a preference pane regarding how this filter will act. I need to take the preferences from this preference pane and load them in to the kernel extension.

I have googled all over and haven't found anything regarding how to do this.

Is there a way to load a plist in to a preference pane? Perhaps into an OSDictionary or something?
Or, what would be the best way to get preferences from my preference pane into my kext?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is exactly what I am looking for:

[Kext Controls and Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/NKEConceptual/control/control.html)

Excellent.

Answer (score 1):

The source code of [this project](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/) will help you. It uses sysctl to communicate between the pref pane and the kext.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look in to that. It looks like it may be a bit limiting as I am passing far more data than a single int, like he is, but it may work.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a kernel extension, you might look into [Quartz Event Services](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html), as it is designed for user-land event filtering.